# Bin execution error

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, assembly, nasm

i'm new to assembly language, I finished writing a simple program so i ran the follow commends

```
nasm -o learn.bin learn.asm
```

to assemble the code then

```
 chmod +x learn.bin
```

and then finally to run it

```
 ./learn.bin
```

but the last returned an error

```
 bash: ./learn.bin: cannot execute binary file
```

im running ubuntu with an atom intel CPU

any help would be awesome, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error message sounds like you don't have a proper ELF executable header on it. It IS possible to assemble a file using Nasm's `-f bin` output format (the default, if you don't specify an output format). But it needs an ELF header stuffed into it.

The usual way would be `nasm -f elf32 learn.asm` (or perhaps `-f elf64` if you've got 64-bit code). This "should" produce "learn.o", if all goes well. Then you've got to link this "linkable object" file using  `ld -o learn learn.o` (add `-melf-i386` if you're using 64-bit `ld`... which you probably are). Or, depending on the code, `gcc -o learn learn.o` (add `-m32` for 64-bit gcc). I see that Jester has just told you that (in fewer words).

Here's an example of a file that "should" work the way you're trying to do it:

```
[map all hkhw.map] ; optional
;==========================
bits 32
ORIGIN equ 8048000h
org ORIGIN
section .text
    code_offset equ 0
    code_addr:
;--------------------------- ELF header----------------------
        dd $464c457f,$00010101,0,0,$00030002,1,main,$34,0,0,$00200034,2,0
        dd 1,code_offset,code_addr,code_addr,code_filez,code_memsz,5,4096
        dd 1,data_offset,data_addr,data_addr,data_filez,data_memsz,6,4096
main:
;--------- your code goes here -------------------------------

    push byte 4
    pop eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ecx, msg
    push byte msg_len
    pop edx
    int 80h

    push byte 1
    pop eax
    int 80h    


;------------ constant data -----------------------
; (note that we're in .text, not .rdata)
        align 4



;-------------------------------------------------------------
        align 4
        code_memsz equ $ - $$
        code_filez equ code_memsz
        data_addr equ (ORIGIN+code_memsz+4095)/4096*4096 + (code_filez % 4096)
        data_offset equ code_filez
section .data vstart=data_addr
;------------ initialized data -------------

msg db "Hello from Nasm, all by itself!", 10
msg_len equ $ - msg

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    idat_memsz equ $ - $$
    bss_addr equ data_addr + ($ - $$)
section .bss  vstart=bss_addr 
;------------- uninitialized data ----------------------



;-------------------------------------------------
    udat_memsz equ $ - $$
    data_memsz equ  idat_memsz + udat_memsz
    data_filez equ  idat_memsz
;========================
```

Well... that didn't format well. Probably unreadable. Try Nasm Forum. We can help you more if you post the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't (normally) run plain binary files under linux. You'll have to create an ELF executable by first asking `nasm` to produce an object file and then using a linker. Note that your code should also of course be written for linux. There are plenty of examples on the internet, see [this tutorial](http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html) for example.

Comment: thank you so much, that explains a lot, now it all works, thank you